# Visual Studio: newlines in SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Is there any way to use newlines in SQL queries in Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition? Whenever I organize my queries with newlines for readability Visual Studio highlights the code as error and the project fails to build (without even mentioning the reason, just a "No source available message"). However, I simply remove the newlines and it builds.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. In what way have you tried it that it didn't work?

Comment: @hvd: I tried adding newlines after each line, that didn't work! But now I know (thanks Thit Lwin Oo) to precede the string literal with `@`.

Comment: I was hoping for a code sample, from which it would have been clear that you were using `""` string literals in C#, so that guessing wouldn't be necessary. But it doesn't matter if you have your answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way..

```
    string sql = @"SELECT ID, NAME
                 FROM TABLE
                 WHERE ID = '1'
                ";
```

Comment: You're assuming the SQL is part of the C# code. What is your basis for assuming that it is part of the code, and what is your basis for assuming that that code is written in C#?

Comment: Thank you, that was it! In this case the SQL is in fact part of the code. However, I am in fact interested in the general case where the SQL is not part of the code. Apparently I'm a bit spoiled by the MySQL CLI interpreter!